# Comparing Array-Types

Tags: java

`public static boolean set(boolean[][] board) { if (board **instanceof Array[8][8]**); return true; }`

How do I write this expression right?
I want to compare the "board" which should be a type of an 8x8 array. My other tasks should only run if the Array-Size is correct.
How do I check it?

Comment: What you want to check is the length of the array. eG check if `board.length == 8` and then if for every i from 0 to 7 `board[i].length == 8`. The length of an array is not related to the type.

Answer (score 1):

getting number of rows and number of columns, then check if number of rows and columns are 8

```
  int[][] boardArray = new int[8][8];
  // returns the length of the rows in the array
  int rows = boardArray.length;
  // returns the length of the columns in the array
  int columns = boardArray[0].length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to compare the array types but the array lengths:

```
public static boolean set(boolean[][] board) {
    if (board.length != 8) {                  // if the outer array doesn't have 8 items
        return false;                         // ... return false
    }
    for (boolean[] array: board) {            // for each inner array
        if (array.length != 8) {              // ... if the array doesn't have 8 items
            return false;                     // ... return false
        }
    }
    return true;                              // if all checks pass, then return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You check the length of the array, this checks the first dimension, then you check each one dimensional array is the right size:

```
public static boolean set(boolean[][] board) { 
    if (board.length!=8) {
        return false;
    }
    return Arrays.stream(board).allMatch(row->row.length==8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different solution is to create a custom class that holds an 8x8 array and then write your methods to only accept/return this class

```
class Board {
    private boolean[][] board = new boolean[8][8];

    public boolean[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    // other methods to work with the board member
 }
```

This way you can also collect all logic you have today to read/update the board content to this class making your code cleaner and easier to test.